# Progess 4GL - How to filter multiple records using AND operator in one table field?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I want to check and filter only if the table has value1 = 005 and value1 = 009. But it seems below query is not helping me. I dont know where I am making mistakes. Kindly help to solve this. Note -  I cannot use where not as it may have many different value stored in value1 field

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE test NO-UNDO
FIELD value1 AS CHARACTER
.

EMPTY TEMP-TABLE test.

CREATE test.
ASSIGN
  value1 = "005".

CREATE test.
ASSIGN
  value1 = "009".

CREATE test.
ASSIGN
  value1 = "001".

FOR EACH test NO-LOCK
   WHERE value1 <> ""
   AND (value1 = "005" AND value1 = "009")
  :

   MESSAGE YES.
END.
```

Comment: What do you mean by “and filter”? Do you need a query that returns all records that have those values (along with some additional criteria?) or do you need something else? Are you expecting a yes/no answer that at least one record meeting each criteria exists? Or maybe the merged set of records meeting either criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use can-find

```
if can-find(first test WHERE value1 = "005") 
   AND can-find(first test WHERE value1 = "009")
then message yes.
```

It is safest to always use can-find(first if you're looking for a non-unique value

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking for an `OR` ooperation, rather than `AND`.

Comment: @nwahmaent - No..there cant be a single record. I need a logic which checks both records 005 and 009 should be present in a table

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if both records are present you could do :

```swift
DEFINE VARIABLE isPresent005 AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE isPresent009 AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE bothPresents AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

FIND FIRST test WHERE test.value1 = "005" NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
isPresent005 = AVAIL test.

FIND FIRST test WHERE test.value1 = "009" NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
isPresent009 = AVAIL test.

bothPresents = isPresent005 AND isPresent009.
```

But, if you only want to get these 2 records, you should use `OR` :

```swift
FOR EACH test WHERE test.value1 = "005" OR test.value1 = "009" NO-LOCK :
    /*do stuff*/
END.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option if you are, maybe, looking for some additional fields might look something like this:

```
define buffer test005 for test.
define buffer test009 for test.

for each test005 no-lock where test005.customer = 1 and test005.value1 = "005",
    each test009 no-lock where test009.customer = 1 and test009.value1 = "009":

  display test005.customer.

end.
```